# Make a login into dbo for a database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, shared-hosting

I am attempting to migrate from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008. Both of these database instances are hosted on 3rd party shared servers that I do not have full permissions to. They are using mixed mode authentication.

I am running into trouble setting up the new database the same way the old one was set up. Specifically, the new web-based control panel doesn't allow a dbo to be specified when creating a new database and then when using Red Gate SQL Compare to sync up the schemas I am having problems because some objects (that don't explicitly specify dbo in the script) are being created with the prefix of the user account rather dbo.

I have poured over the documentation trying to find a way to force my login "user1" as dbo to the "db1" database. I came to the conclusion that the script should look like this:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::db1 TO user1
```

Before running this script, the login "user1" already exists, but is not a user for database "db1". Note I had to submit this script to the support of my hosting company in order to run it. According to the hosting company the statement successfully executes, however when I compare the databases using SQL Compare the user "user1" has not been physically added to the database like it was under SQL Server 2005. When trying to add it using the script:

```
CREATE USER [user1] FOR LOGIN [user1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

I get the error message:

```
"The login already has an account under a different username"
```

I have tried dropping all of the other users from the database, but the error message still persists - which I find odd.

While I could just fix the scripts by explicitly specifying dbo, this would inevitably be a time bomb waiting to go off because if any new script were introduced that didn't explicitly specify dbo there would be a failure during synchronization. Since some of the scripts are from 3rd parties, this is not a good solution.

So my questions: Is there another statement that I need to run in order to add "user1" to the database as a user that is dbo? Is there anything that has changed in the implementation between SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 R2 that could cause these inconsistencies?

I am unfortunately not able to test to find an answer to the second one because I don't have another SQL Server 2008 database to test with and I don't have full access to do anything I want on this one.

The old database was created through a control panel which forced dbo to be specified and the new one doesn't allow dbo to be specified when creating a database.

Comment: so [user1] is a sql server level login and can be seen in master.dbo.syslogins and there is no user in [database].dbo.sysusers which has the same sid

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Yes, that is exactly the case. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Just been looking at this again this morning and i have managed to recreate the same error. However you have already said you have "dropp[ed] all of the other users"... Have you dropped user1 on the database and recreated it too? Try the following code to see all the mappings between logins and users "select l.name as ServerLoginName, u.name as DatabaseUserName from [database].dbo.sysusers u join master.dbo.syslogins l on u.sid = l.sid"

Comment: No, I didn't drop "user1" before. I ran the query and got 1 result - ServerLoginName: user1, DatabaseUserName: dbo. I guess that explains why I can't create the db user. I ran the same query in production and the DatabaseUserName was "user1", not "dbo". I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905208%28v=sql.80%29.aspx which explains the issue better - my current login is not mapped to "dbo" but is a member of the sysadmin role. Now it is just a matter of making a script to make the login a member of sysadmin - currently I don't know how to do this, though.

Comment: Oops, I guess the production user is not a member of sysadmin (ran sp_helpsrvrolemember to check). In that case, I have no idea how the old user could create objects prefixed with "dbo". However, since my new login is mapped to "dbo" it should be functionally equivalent to the old user - I guess I could just create a copy of the production database and, modify the users to match the new server, and then I will be able to synchronize the schema from the copy (in theory).

Comment: You wont be able to give SA rights unless you are an SA on the production server yourself. However from the sounds of it all you need to do now is the following.  "ALTER USER [user1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]" The create wasnt working as it already existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what i have gathered the following should suffice.

```
ALTER USER [user1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

The create wasnt working as it already existed.

Comment: How does this differ from what I already have? I mean, "user1" is already dbo, right? Is giving the default schema dbo functionally equivalent to making the user the dbo (with respect to creating objects)?

Comment: except you were worried about new tables/functions being created under the user1 schema which was why you stated you would have had to explicitly state dbo.[tablename]. By setting the default schema to dbo then you wont need to express dbo in the create statments

Comment: Ok, I tested this method using SQL Compare and it worked - this indeed was why the 2005 server was acting like it was. In addition, if the database is updated this way it doesn't require a support request to run any SQL scripts that I don't have permission to run.